# Not receiving data on the mobile phone with flutter app

Tags: android, flutter

I have made an application that receives a data real time using a pusher.
This app works properly in the emulator but it doesn't work on the mobile phone.

```dart
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  PusherChannelsFlutter pusher = PusherChannelsFlutter.getInstance();
  String data = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    _initPusher();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(body: Text(data)),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _initPusher() async {
    PusherChannelsFlutter pusher = PusherChannelsFlutter.getInstance();
    try {
      await pusher.init(
          apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
          cluster: 'xxxxxxx',
          onEvent: (myEvent) {
            setState(() {
              data = myEvent.data;
            });
          });

      await pusher.subscribe(channelName: 'my_channel');
      await pusher.connect();
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("ERROR: $e");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Andorid Manifest  permission

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
> ```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It is possible (likely) that the `_initPusher` called from `initState` completes later than the `build` method. Try to use a `FutureBuilder`, generally you should avoid calling async functions in `initState`.

Comment: what is the error bro ?

Comment: @DewaPrabawa I do not receive an error

Comment: @AhmadDae I do not receive an error

Comment: add setState(() {}) after  await pusher.connect();